# Incorrect return value javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple guessing game and my return value or my functionality seems correct. I have console.logged typeof for my input value as well as my randNum value and they are both numbers. However my alert is always incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

```
var currentGuess = false;
var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
var input = document.getElementById("guess").value;
var input = parseInt(input);
var btn = document.getElementById("submit");
var results = document.getElementById("results");
console.log(randNum);

function check() {
    checkNum(input, randNum);

    if( input === randNum) {
        alert("correct");
    } else {
        alert("incorrect");
    }
}

function checkNum(guess, actualNum) {
    currentGuess = false;
    if(guess === actualNum) {
        return true;
    } 
    return currentGuess;
}

btn.addEventListener("click", check, false);
```

Comment: please describe what output you get and what you expect.

Comment: What is the point of the checkNum function? You don't do anything with the return value.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't take input again when check is called.

just add this in your check function

```
input = parseInt(document.getElementById("guess").value);
```

Like this

```
function check() {
    input = parseInt(document.getElementById("guess").value);
    checkNum(input, randNum);

    if( input === randNum) {
        alert("correct");
    } else {
        alert("incorrect");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks you were correct but why do I have to do that if I already made a global var doing so? Thanks

Comment: You have declared as a global variable. That's why you can access anywhere within the boundary. But when you press click, it'll keep previous value which it took at the first time. In order to get the latest value, you have take input again @user8280738

Comment: @JapanGuy I understand the different of them. === is both types have to matched. But as I said I already declared a global var that parses the string value of that input to a a number. I am just trying to understand why I have to redeclare it within my function.

Comment: @user8280738 actually you are not re-declaring again. You are just taking input again

Comment: `.value` is a value type. it won't change when textbox updates @user8280738

Comment: @user8280738 What seems to be the confusion here is that when you assign (operator =) something to a variable, that assignation will never change by itself, you make a contract with that variable to hold what you give it. If you assign a reference (like the input element), the reference won't change but some properties inside the referenced object may have changed. If you assign a value directly (like the input value in that element), this value will also never change by itself, hence if you use it again later it will hold the same value.

Answer (score -1):

Fiddle with working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/pp9Lrpe6/

You are listening for the click even on the input, but getting the input value when everything is loaded, which is empty - returning input = NaN.  This value isn't updated when a user clicks:

```
    var randNum, btn, results;

    // Generate random number.
    randNum = Math.floor( Math.random() * 100 );

    // Submit button to listen for click events on.
    btn = document.getElementById( 'submit' );

    // Display result one at a time in #results.
    results = document.getElementById( 'results' );

    // Number to guess.
    console.log( 'Random number: ' + randNum );

    // Check the input on click of #submit
    function check() {
            var input = parseInt( document.getElementById( 'guess' ).value, 10 );
        if ( input === randNum ) {
                    results.innerHTML = '<p class="correct">' + input + ' is correct!</p>';
        } else {
                    results.innerHTML = '<p class="incorrect">' + input + ' is not correct!</p>';
        }
    }

    // Add event listener for #submit
    btn.addEventListener( 'click', check, false );
```

As a good practice, you should give you input the type="number".
You should also declare the radix for parseInt ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt))

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="guess"><br>
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="check"><br>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <script>
        var currentGuess = false;
        var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
        var btn = document.getElementById("submit");
        var results = document.getElementById("results");
        console.log(randNum);

        function check() {
            var input = document.getElementById("guess").value;
            var input = parseInt(input);
            if( input === randNum) {
                alert("correct");
            } else {
                alert("incorrect");
            }
        }

        btn.addEventListener("click", check, false);
    </script>
</body>
```